# Least squares wih variable bounds

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

Consider the following variant of the least squares problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{}{\text{minimize}} & \|y - X  \beta\|_{2}^{2}\\ \text{subject to} & \beta \in \left[0,1 \right]^{n}, \end{array}$$

where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $X$ has full column rank. Without restriction on $\beta$ the unique solution is given by
$$
\beta^{0} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y.
$$
Is there also a closed form solution for the restricted problem? If not, what is the best approach to tackle this problem. I think one way is proximal gradient method. My idea is first to solve the unconstrained version (i.e., project the vector on the column space of $X$) giving the vector $a = X\beta^{0}$ and then find the vector $\tilde\beta$ which minimizes
$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{}{\text{minimize}} & \|a - X  \beta\|_{2}^{2}\\ \text{subject to} & \beta \in \left[0,1 \right]^{n}. \end{array}$$
Or is the solution given by

$\tilde\beta_{i} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \beta_{i}^{0} < 0 \\
1 & \beta_{i}^{0} >1 \\
\beta_{i}^{0} & \beta_{i}^{0} \in [0,1]^{n}.
\end{array}
\right. $

Here I denote with $\beta^{0}$ the solution of the least squares problem without constraints given above.

Comment: maybe you could try with Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: @FlorianIngels How should I write the constraint if I try Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: You would have two constraints per dimension; $\beta_i \geq 0$ and $\beta_i \leq 1$ so I would say you would have $2n$ multipliers. Actually, it's not Lagrange Multipliers but rather KKT conditions that you should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush-Kuhn-Tucker_conditions

Comment: There is no closed form solution to this problem. But you can easily solve it using prox-grad, which is an iterative method. Moreover, since this is a convex problem with a simple constraint set you can use and accelerate prox-grad scheme, such as FISTA, to get a faster solution to the problem

Comment: Use any  linearly-constrained linear least squares function, of which there are many.